# GridView CheckBox Select is taking last value of Column in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, asp.net-membership

I using membership to create user and assign them roles for this i have written following codes in my aspx page...After entering user details in Creatuser form wizard there is another option to select user role which is displayed in gridview with check box but whatever role u select from  gridview checkbox it is taking last value only and inserting the user with the same role whereas i want it to be inserted with the selected value...

Here is my client side code in aspx page..

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;
        width: 339px; height: 203px;">
        <table width="400">
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>Sign Up for New User Account</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    UserName:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqfUserName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Password:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPwd"
                        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ForeColor="Red" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Confirm Password:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCnfPwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordConfirmRequiredValidator" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="txtCnfPwd" ForeColor="red" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" />
                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordConfirmCompareValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCnfPwd"
                        ForeColor="red" Display="Dynamic" ControlToCompare="txtPwd" ErrorMessage="Confirm password must match password." />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Create User" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1" colspan="3">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" Font-Bold="true" />
                </td>
                <td class="style2" colspan="1">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan"
                    BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Here is my server side code...aspx.cs

```
string Role;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindRoles();

    }

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        getrole();

        showuser();


    }
}

protected void BindRoles()
{
    gvRoles.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles();
    gvRoles.DataBind();
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
    MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPwd.Text, null, null, null, true, out createStatus);
    switch (createStatus)
    {
        //This Case Occured whenver User Created Successfully in database
        case MembershipCreateStatus.Success:



            lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblResult.Text = "The   " + txtUserName.Text + "   account was successfully created with  " +Role+ "";
            txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;

            break;
        // This Case Occured whenver we send duplicate UserName
        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
            lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblResult.Text = "The user with the same UserName already exists!";
            break;
        //This Case Occured whenver we give duplicate mail id
        case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
            lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblResult.Text = "The user with the same email address already exists!";
            break;
        //This Case Occured whenver we send invalid mail format
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
            lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblResult.Text = "The email address you provided is invalid.";
            break;
        //This Case Occured whenver we send empty data or Invalid Data
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
            lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblResult.Text = "The security answer was invalid.";
            break;
        // This Case Occured whenver we supplied weak password
        case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
            lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblResult.Text = "The password you provided is invalid. It must be 7 characters long and have at least 1 special character.";
            break;
        default:
            lblResult.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblResult.Text = "There was an unknown error; the user account was NOT created.";
            break;
    }

    }

public void getrole()
{

    string roleName = string.Empty;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvRoles.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkRole");
        Label lbl = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblRole");
        roleName = lbl.Text;
        Role=roleName;
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(txtUserName.Text, roleName);
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            Label1.Text = "The   " + txtUserName.Text + "  role  " + roleName + "  Added  ";
            //Label1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}

public void showuser() {

    GridView1.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Please guys help me as i am stuck in this condition ...will be gratfull..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This is because you are filling in RoleName outside the if condition before checking if the checkbox is checked or not.

```
public void getrole()
{

    string roleName = string.Empty;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvRoles.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkRole");
        Label lbl = (Label)gvrow.FindControl("lblRole");

        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            roleName = lbl.Text;
            Role=roleName;
            Roles.AddUserToRole(txtUserName.Text, roleName);
            Label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            Label1.Text = "The   " + txtUserName.Text + "  role  " + roleName + "  Added  ";
            //Label1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```